# The correct way to calculate the height of cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

In my app, it have about thousand contents to display in tableView. Each of content has different heights since there are one to three lines UILabel in it. Currently, it calculates and returns the heights of each cell in the tableView delegate function:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

And the way it calculate is:

```
contentCell = (RSContentViewCell *)self.tmpCell;
UIFont *font = contentCell.myTextLabel.font;
width = contentCell.myTextLabel.frame.size.width + 30;

size = [contentStr sizeWithFont:font
    constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(width, CGFLOAT_MAX)
    lineBreakMode:contentCell.myTextLabel.lineBreakMode];

height = size.height;
return height;
```

It works but takes about 0.5 secs to calculate those heights, so the UX is not so good, since the app will be no response during the calculation process.
So what's the correct way and where is the correct place to calculate heights of these cell?

**UPDATE**

The data is from the server and requested at the time that entering the table view.

Comment: one single call of this function takes 0.5 secs?

Comment: That doesn't sound right to me either.

Comment: thousand cells take 0.5 secs

Comment: 30 is the magic width number ? You don't need to calculate all the cells height at once, the `tableview` will request the cell height as it needs to be drawn.

Comment: @A-Live at first the table will call this methods for all cells to calculate its contentSize. So this will take a while with thousand cells.

Comment: As my experiment, the `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` will be invoked for all the cell once the tableView reload data. So this function will be executed thousand times at once.

Comment: @A-Live the `30` is another problem that the height isn't calculated correctly. I will deal it later.

Comment: My bad, have forgotten about not paged tables with thousands of cells.

Answer (score 1):

As you are laoding your Data from a Server you do have a delay no matter what.

=> I suggest you do the Height calculating in background bevor you reload the table / remove the spinner etc.

```
// Method you call when your data is fetched
- (void)didReciveMyData:(NSArray *)dataArray {
    // start background job
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        self.myCachedHeightArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[dataArray count]];
        int i = 0;
        for (id data in dataArray) {
            float height;

            // do height calculation

            self.myCachedHeightArray[i] = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:height];// assign result to height results
            i++;
        }

        // reload your view on mainthread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self doActualReload];
        });
    });
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return [[self.myCachedHeightArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] floatValue];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I put this into my custom cell subclass usually... so the code doesn't clutter my controller and is correct for the cell I use. (+ it is better suited to MVC that way... the height of a cell is a view property IMO)

I DONT measure with each cell, but with a static method - see https://github.com/Daij-Djan/TwitterSearchExampleApp (the ViewController and the DDTweetTableViewCell class for an example)

Answer (score 0):

You still have to do this on the front end but only do it once and cache the results in an Array and use that for future calls.

i.e. The first time the array value is empty so calculate it and store it in the array.

The next time the array has a value so use that without having to calculate.

Comment: So where should I put the calculation code in? Since this function will be executed only when table view reload data, so the cache technique may not so helpful.

Answer (score 0):

How do you set/get self.tmpCell ? Do you save the reusable cell in a property?

Instead getting text from cell and calculating the size you can calculate the size of text from data source of the cell. I mean you set the texts in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` somehow (eg. from an array) just use the text from that to calculate it.

For the frame : The cells have the same width of tableview
For the font : Just write a method called

```
- (UIFont *)fontForCellAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexpath
```

and use it also from `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. It makes your job easier if you change the fonts of texts later.

Comment: The self.tmpCell will be only initialized at the first time by `if (self.tmpCell == nil)`.

Comment: You do not have only one cell, right? You just save some cell in a property. Actually you can not know when iOS calls your heightForRowAtIndexPath method for which cell, but you have got the indexPath. Tableview can have more cells at a time, but you save just one. I updated my answer